# When running a t-test with a Control and Experimental group, are both groups Samples? Or is the Control group a Population?

Tags: statistics

When running a t-test with a Control and Experimental group, are both groups Samples? Or is the Control group a Population? I am pretty confused on this, since I've pretty much only ever worked with Samples, but have no idea when to switch to a population

Comment: Typically there would both be seen as samples, and you are interested whether they are different and what is the difference between them, or between their statistics, or in statistics of their differences

Answer (score 0):

If you use a 2-sample t test, then you're assuming data from Treatment and Control
groups are both samples. In many cases the two samples are of about the same size.
If you're designing an experiment, trying to know how much data to collect in order
to have a reasonable chance of detecting a difference between the two groups, and
you have a given number of subjects available, then it's most efficient to put half of the subjects (at random) into each group.

However, sometimes you have a situation in which huge control group already exists
(say 100,000) and you imagine you can randomly take a smaller random sample (say 100) from the same population to use for a treatment group. Then it might not make much difference whether
you do a two sample t test on the two groups, or you do a one-sample t test comparing
the sample mean from the small control group against the mean of the huge
group--regarded as a population mean.

**Examples 1:** Two small groups of about the same size.

Generate fake data for illustration:

```
set.seed(1234)
x.c = rnorm(100, 50, 5)
x.t = rnorm(100, 51, 5)
```

A boxplot show the treatment values (top) tend to be a little larger.

```
boxplot(x.c, x.t, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

A two-sample t test finds a significant difference (at the 5% level) between the mean $49.22$ of the control group and the mean $51.21$ of the treatment group
because the P-value $0.0064 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
t.test(x.c, x.t)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x.c and x.t
t = -2.7635, df = 197.85, p-value = 0.006258
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.4101030 -0.5699462
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 49.21619  51.20622
```

**Example 2:** Huge control group and small treatment group.

```
set.seed(1235)
x.c = rnorm(100000, 50, 5)
x.t = rnorm(100, 51, 5)
```

A boxplot shows that the smaller control values (upper boxplot) tend
to be larger. [It is typical for a huge normal sample to show many boxplot 'outliers'.]

```
 boxplot(x.c, x.t, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

A two-sample t test finds a significant difference (at the 5% level) between the mean $59.92$ of the control group and the mean $51.09$ of the treatment group
because the P-value $0.036 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
t.test(x.c, x.t)

       Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x.c and x.t
t = -2.1268, df = 99.195, p-value = 0.03592
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.0685429 -0.0717558
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 50.01799  51.08814
```

**Example 3:** Considering the huge control group as a population.

The mean of the control group is taken as $\mu = 50.02$ and we compare the *sample* mean of the control group to $\mu.$ In the boxplot below, the vertical line indicates
the position of $\mu.$

```
boxplot(x.t, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
 abline(v = 50.02, col="red")
```

[image]

A one-sample t test finds a significant difference (at the 5% level) between the *population* mean $50.02$ of the control "population" and the sample mean $51.09$ of the smaller treatment group
because the P-value is $0.036 < 0.05.$ Here we are ignoring any variability in the 'control' group, taking $\mu = 50.02$ as an established value. Even with a 'control population'
as large as $100\,000$ this may be risky.

```
t.test(x.t, mu=50.02)   # Null population mean shown

    One Sample t-test

data:  x.t
t = 2.1238, df = 99, p-value = 0.03618
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 50.02
95 percent confidence interval:
  50.09021 52.08607
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 51.08814
```